# Inconsistent results from phpmyadmin and Codeigniter's $this->db->query() function

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

User table

```
id  stamp_created          email_address
1   2013-03-06 22:00:01    test+1@gmail.com
2   2013-03-20 22:00:08    test+2@gmail.com
3   2013-03-27 22:00:17    test+3@gmail.com
4   2013-04-01 22:00:27    test+4@gmail.com
```

I have this query

```
SELECT
    `user`.*
FROM
    `user`
WHERE
    `user`.`email_address` IS NOT NULL
    AND (`user`.`stamp_created` BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-04-01 23:59:59')
```

When running the query in phpmyadmin, I got the correct results

```
4   2013-04-01 22:00:27    test+4@gmail.com
```

but when I run the query via

```
$sql = "SELECT
    `user`.*
FROM
    `user`
WHERE
    `user`.`email_address` IS NOT NULL
    AND (`user`.`stamp_created` BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2013-04-01 23:59:59')
";

$this->db->query($sql)->result_array();
```

I get an empty array.

Any idea why this is the case?

P.S. Already confirmed that CI and phpmyadmin is using the same database so that is not the issue.

Comment: What's in `$sql`? Can you show how you're assigning the SQL string to it?

Comment: @Phil Updated my question to show you what is inside the $sql variable.

Comment: How did you confirm you're using the same DB in both instances?

Comment: What happens if you try a slightly more simplified query, like - `select * from user`?

Comment: @Phil I outputted the database name and host in Codeigniter

Comment: @Jeemusu I tried testing the WHERE clause and the problem only arises when the "stamp created BETWEEN" filter is there.

Comment: how about ditching the between and just using `stamp_created >= 2013-04-01 00:00:00 AND stamp_created <= 2013-04-01 23:59:59`

Comment: @Jeemusu Nope, still did not work.

Comment: try using CI's active record class and see whats the results you get. I mean, using things like `$this->db->where()`

Comment: @arvinsim is the return value is null? if it is the issue you should **return $this->db->query($sql)->result_array();**

Comment: @Noel_Yahan The value returned is an empty array.

Comment: I do something very similar to this, and I use active record with code that would look like this: 
  `$this->db->where('stamp_created >= ', '2013-04-01 00:00:00'); $this->db->where('stamp_created <= ', 2013-04-01 23:59:59); `

Comment: First, run $this->db->last_query() and confirm the query sent is the same as you think.

Comment: @jmadsen I tried it and yes, they are exactly the same.

Comment: then it is something in the code after your ->result_array() ...you are somehow losing the array variable holding the results.

Post the rest of your model function & controller

Comment: @arvinsim yes please post complete functions in model and controller

Comment: There is no "inbetween code" from the ->result_array() to outputting the value. Immediately after assigning the value to the variable, I outputted it.

Comment: have you tryed changing the WHERE statement to check if the result changes? CI might be magicaly striping your `'` characters in the where clause, try changing it to `BETWEEN date(20130401) AND date(20130402)`

Answer (score 0):

What if you try

```
$query = $this->db->sql('yourquery');

if($query->num_rows() > 0){
   foreach($query->result() as $row){
      $retdat[] = array(
           'test1' => $row->stamp_created
     ); 
  }
    print_r($retdat);
}
```